# Parar proceso de la función setInterval() en cuenta atrás

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Probando cosas en Javascript me he encontrado con la siguiente duda. Supongamos que tengo un botón que inicia una cuenta atrás. Al llegar a 0 la cuenta se termina. 
Partiendo de un html super sencillo solo con el objetivo de hacer el test:

```
<button>TEST</button>
<p>5</p>
```

He credo un script donde uso la función **setInterval** de la siguiente manera:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const counter = document.querySelector('p');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 clearInterval(time);
 counter.innerHTML = 5;
 const time = setInterval(() => {
 counter.innerHTML--;
  if (counter.innerHTML == 0) {
     clearInterval(time);
   }
  }, 1000)
})
```

Esto funciona a medias. Si pulso botón y dejo que llegue a 0 el contador, todo perfecto. El problema surge cuando vuelvo pulsar el botón de **TEST** sin que el contador llegue a 0. Al no haber llegado a 0, no se ha ejecutado la funciona **clearInterval** y el contador no funciona correctamente.

Esto lo resuelvo poniendo la variable **time** que guarda el **setInterval** como variable global:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const counter = document.querySelector('p');
var time = "";
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 clearInterval(time);
 counter.innerHTML = 5;
 time = setInterval(() => {
 counter.innerHTML--;
  if (counter.innerHTML == 0) {
     clearInterval(time);
   }
  }, 1000)
})
```

Es una solución valida. La duda que me surge es.¿Se podría para el **setInterval** de alguna otra manera y evitar definir una variable global?

Simplemente es una duda que me surge. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice esto por si te funciona.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="btn">
            Test
        </button>
        <p id="cont">5</p>
    </body>
    <script>
        let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        let cont = document.getElementById("cont");
        btn.onclick = ()=>{
            cont.innerHTML = 5;
            let time = setInterval(()=>{
                if(cont.innerHTML == 0 || time>1){
                    clearInterval(time);
                    time = 0;
                    return 0;
                }
                cont.innerHTML--;
            }, 1000);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde tengo entendido es imposible pausarlo. Pero te ofresco una alternativa:

- Calcula los milisegundos restantes y guardalos en una variable y luego llama a clearInterval.
- Para reanudar el temporizador llamas a un setTimeout y le asignas los milisegundos que guardaste en la variable anterior.
- Y por untimo, en el callback del setTimeout llamas al setInterval nuevamente.